# how to display scrollbar inside container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to display scrollbar inside container on content overflow like facebook notifications?

setting `overflow:auto` displaying scrollbar outside container.

How to render scrollbar outside container?

Comment: please create a fiddle or show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the overflow should take care of it, but you need to set the height of content also. If the height attribute is not set, the div will grow vertically as tall as it needs to, and scrollbars wont be needed.

```
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="Content">
   blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.FixedHeightContainer {
     float:right;
     height: 250px;
     width:250px; 
     padding:3px; 
     background:#f00;
}

.Content {
    height:224px;
    overflow:auto;
    background:#fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ftkbL/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this plugin [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

Include jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css inside the head tag your html document

```
<link href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Include jQuery library

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
```

call mCustomScrollbar

```
<script>
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".content").mCustomScrollbar();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[Demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/scrollbar_themes_demo.html)